# String Index OutOfBOunds Exception

Tags: java, string, exception, indexing

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(".../senses/command_list"));
    String line = null;

    while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
        if(line.isEmpty()){
            continue;
        }
        line = line.trim();
        line = line.substring(2 + line.indexOf(">") , line.indexOf("))"));
        System.out.println(line);

    }
```

Following is an extract of the file

```
en_actions_.add(new ClusterEntry<String>("photography",-1, 2, 620554,"photography",null));
en_actions_.add(new ClusterEntry<String>("diagnostic procedure",-1, 1, 177127,"diagnostic procedure",null));
en_actions_.add(new ClusterEntry<String>("emergency procedure",-1, 1, 177783,"emergency procedure",null));
en_actions_.add(new ClusterEntry<String>("medical procedure",-1, 1, 1024392,"medical procedure",null));
en_actions_.add(new ClusterEntry<String>("process",-1, 5, 5470189,"process",null));
```

When I run this program, I encounter a String out of bounds exception with the following error message

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2**
and it points to the line with the indexOf operator.

Please let me know what I have done wrong.BTW the purpose, of the program is to store each field in an array of structures/classes. This is just the first part of the program.

Comment: for sure the problem is with your substring call. this error happens when you excedes  the maximum length for the string. check if that part(2+ line.indexOf(">")) is not greater than the total length of the string

Comment: Try surrounding the body of the loop with a try...catch block that prints the offending line to standard error.

Comment: It prints most of the lines. The exception pops up somewhere in the middle.

Comment: maybe not related to your question, but why not extracting the text via regex? it saves the index calculations...

Comment: @Kent i am not familiar with the working of Regex.. I should really learn that.

Comment: Surrounding with try/catch block eliminates the exception, but shouldn't it be working fine without that as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like one of the lines in the file doesn't have a `>` or `)` character. In fact I don't see the `>` in your file data at all. One of the operators might be multiline. Extract the `indexOf` into separate variables and check that those symbols are there.

```
int index1 = line.indexOf(">");
if (index1 < 0) {
 //skip this line
 continue;
}
```

Also, you might want to swap the `trim` and `isEmpty` check so it would filter out lines consisting of just whitespaces.

Comment: > character is in <String>. I will try swapping that.

Comment: Swapping the trim and isEmpty commands worked, but I have no idea why. Could you tell me how? Thank You !

Comment: @user3645570 Imagine that you had a line with a bunch of whitespaces in the end of the file, or the line with non-printable characters. If you test the line with `isEmpty` it will not work because string is technically not empty. If you do `trim` first those characters will be removed and `isEmpty` will do what it supposed.

Answer (score 3):

Well I don't know about what kind of String(line) your file has but it might happen that you get a String of length 1 in which case the following line would produce the exception.

```
line = line.substring(2 + line.indexOf(">") , line.indexOf(")"));
```

Moreover, if your String(line) doesn't have ')', then in that case line.indexOf(")") will give -1 which makes no sense.

Also, try the following code yourself and the same exception as yours will reproduce.

```
String x = "a";
System.out.println(x.substring(2 + x.indexOf(">") , x.indexOf(")")));
```

In String x, store any String that doesn't contains both '>' and ')'.

Comment: Every line in the file is of the format I have specified in the question. I am pretty sure there is no line that has a string of length 1.

Answer (score 1):

the cause of your exception is relatively clear. back to your requirement, I think it is typical regex use case. Because

- it saves you from indexOf() calculation.
- it saves the error handling part, E.g. the `index=-1` case
- depends on the jdk version you used, if <7, subString() has potential mem leak problem. with regex, you don't have that risk.

.

```
String s = "en_actions_.add(new ClusterEntry<String>(\"photography\",-1, 2, 620554,\"photography \",null));";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=>\\()[^)]*");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
```

above codes has a  look-behind regex, to get text between `>(` and `)`, if you like you can added `<string>(` as look-behind pattern.

I would remove the answer, if it is kind of off topic.

Answer (score 1):

2 things can happen:

1. line.indexOf(")") will return -1 if String(line) doesnot contain ')'
2. line.indexOf(")") < line.indexOf(">") if ')' appears before '>' in String(line)

and substring(begin_index,end_index) function will throw IndexOutOfBoundsException if beginIndex is larger than endIndex